# Can't get WebPack installed in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webpack

I am trying to get started with WebPack with an Angular2 application in Visual Studio 2015.  My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "tslint": "3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

WebPack won't seem to install.  My Dependencies tree shows "Dependencies - not installed"

[image]

If I remove the "webpack": "^1.14.0" line from package.json then the "...not installed" goes away so I know this is related to WebPack.

I noticed that the following errors showed up in the Output window for Bower/npm:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I thought that might be the cause of the problem so I followed the steps [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042) to mark fsevents as optional and not try to install it, but it still won't work.

I am on node v7.4.0 and npm v4.1.1.

Any ideas why I can't get WebPack to install?

**UPDATE 1**

So just out of curiosity to see if it had anything to do with Angular or any of the other libraries, I created a brand new ASP.NET Core Web Application and didn't install anything else except WebPack.  Same result.  I tried several versions of WebPack and it just doesn't seem to be happy with VS2015 ASP.NET Core Web Application.

**UPDATE 2**

So apparently this is not uncommon.  I found [this post](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/08/27/how-to-set-up-angular-and-webpack-in-visual-studio-with-asp-net-core/) that walks through setting up WebPack with Angular and ASP.NET Core and the same thing exists there.  I guess the answer is to just ignore it?